# Adding same-name elements to XML file during WiX installation?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2012, wix, wix3.7

I'm trying to get the following [cropped] XML added to a .config file using WiX's util:XmlConfig -

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

One recent attempt for this can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2bsWnCpd), but either way it's not working. I've tried other approaches but in one way or another they all fail. How would I use XMLUConfig to add these similar named dependentAssembly elements and access them to add and update the child assemblyIdentity elements?

I'll also mention I have a working CustomAction in C# that currently fulfills this role, but I gather that it's not the best way to go about it (since it doesn't natively support uninstalling).

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, this answer can give you a hint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869589/wix-xmlconfig-purpose-for-nesting-xmlconfig-in-xmlconfig/13878147#13878147 The point is to have nested `XmlConfig` elements to do the job

Comment: Took me a while to get to it, but I don't think this will help. The method in that answer would require that my <dependentAssembly> element have some distinguishing information to search on, for instance how you searched on the name=yamaha.

A better example for that would be what if there were multiple <motos> elements and you had to choose the second one to add the yamaha elements to?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, which I found was due to the sequence in which I was accessing the dependentAssembly elements with the index in my ElementPath. I hadn't created my dependentAssembly elements before trying to access them with XPath.

In order to generate the following in my web.config:

```
<runtime>
<x:assemblyBinding xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <x:dependentAssembly>
    <x:assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <x:bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </x:dependentAssembly>
  <x:dependentAssembly>
    <x:assemblyIdentity name="LaunchDarkly.Logging" publicKeyToken="d9182e4b0afd33e7" culture="neutral"/>
    <x:bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
  </x:dependentAssembly>
  <x:dependentAssembly>
    <x:assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
    <x:bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.2" newVersion="7.0.0.2"/>
  </x:dependentAssembly>
  <x:dependentAssembly>
    <x:assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
    <x:bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2"/>
  </x:dependentAssembly>
</x:assemblyBinding>
```

I used the following wix code:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_Runtime" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration" Name="runtime" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="1" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime"/>
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_Assembly_Binding" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime" Name="x:assemblyBinding" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="2" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_Assembly_Binding_Xmlns" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_Assembly_Binding" Name="xmlns:x" Value="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"/>
</util:XmlConfig>

<!-- Dependent assemblies -->
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding" Name="x:dependentAssembly" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="3" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly" />
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding" Name="x:dependentAssembly" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="3" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]1[\]]" />
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding" Name="x:dependentAssembly" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="3" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]2[\]]" />
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding" Name="x:dependentAssembly" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="3" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]3[\]]" />

<!-- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe -->
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly" Name="x:assemblyIdentity" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly/x:assemblyIdentity">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity" Name="name" Value="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity" Name="publicKeyToken" Value="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity_3" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_AssemblyIdentity" Name="culture" Value="neutral" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_BindingRedirect" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly" Name="x:bindingRedirect" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly/x:bindingRedirect">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_BindingRedirect_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_BindingRedirect" Name="oldVersion" Value="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_BindingRedirect_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly0_BindingRedirect" Name="newVersion" Value="6.0.0.0" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<!-- LaunchDarkly.Logging -->
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]1[\]]" Name="x:assemblyIdentity" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]1[\]]/x:assemblyIdentity">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity" Name="name" Value="LaunchDarkly.Logging" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity" Name="publicKeyToken" Value="d9182e4b0afd33e7" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity_3" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_AssemblyIdentity" Name="culture" Value="neutral" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_BindingRedirect" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]1[\]]" Name="x:bindingRedirect" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]1[\]]/x:bindingRedirect">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_BindingRedirect_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_BindingRedirect" Name="oldVersion" Value="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_BindingRedirect_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly1_BindingRedirect" Name="newVersion" Value="2.0.0.0" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<!-- System.Text.Json -->
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]2[\]]" Name="x:assemblyIdentity" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]2[\]]/x:assemblyIdentity">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity" Name="name" Value="System.Text.Json" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity" Name="publicKeyToken" Value="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity_3" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_AssemblyIdentity" Name="culture" Value="neutral" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_BindingRedirect" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]2[\]]" Name="x:bindingRedirect" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]2[\]]/x:bindingRedirect">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_BindingRedirect_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_BindingRedirect" Name="oldVersion" Value="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.2" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_BindingRedirect_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly2_BindingRedirect" Name="newVersion" Value="7.0.0.2" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<!-- System.Memory -->
<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]3[\]]" Name="x:assemblyIdentity" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]3[\]]/x:assemblyIdentity">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity" Name="name" Value="System.Memory" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity" Name="publicKeyToken" Value="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity_3" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_AssemblyIdentity" Name="culture" Value="neutral" />
</util:XmlConfig>

<util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_BindingRedirect" Action="create" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]3[\]]" Name="x:bindingRedirect" Node="element" On="install" Sequence="4" VerifyPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[\[]3[\]]/x:bindingRedirect">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_BindingRedirect_1" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_BindingRedirect" Name="oldVersion" Value="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_BindingRedirect_2" File="[PROJECTNAME]\web.config" ElementId="ProjectName_DependentAssembly3_BindingRedirect" Name="newVersion" Value="4.0.1.2" />
</util:XmlConfig>
```

The key component of getting the assemblyIdentity and bindingRedirect elements in the dependentAssembly which you want is to use the index within the ElementPath like in my code above:

> ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/x:assemblyBinding/x:dependentAssembly[[]2[]]"

The x: prefix is used to define the namespace for every element including and beneath assemblyBinding.
VerifyPath will ensures that an element will only be created if it doesn't already exist.