# How to add a xml node using WIX

Tags: wix

I have wix installer which needs to modify a configuration file during installation. It needs to add the following nodes in the xml file under the elemnt named configuration.This is the sample . I would like to add the appsettings node as well in the xml.

```html
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Image" value="C:\Images"/>
  </appSettings>
```

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Image" value="C:\Images"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: This answer can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869589/wix-xmlconfig-purpose-for-nesting-xmlconfig-in-xmlconfig/13878147#13878147

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869589/wix-xmlconfig-purpose-for-nesting-xmlconfig-in-xmlconfig/13878147#13878147 this one helped me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869589/wix-xmlconfig-purpose-for-nesting-xmlconfig-in-xmlconfig/13878147#13878147 . This one finally helped.